I'm trying to use a combo box in excel and it's not populating?
I'm using excel on Mac and trying to setup a combo box. I've added the box to sheet1.
I've right clicked on the object and selected "Format Controls". In the "Input Range" I've entered: $A$1:$A$5, and "Cell Link" is: $C$1.
My Sheet1 Looks similar to this: where the values for the combo box are A1:A5 and the user selection should show in C1 (like below).



A
B
C




Cat

bird


dog

3


mouse




snake




bird










However in my case the combo box and cell C1 are both empty, and nothing happens when I click the combo box. I tried the same with a list box link to cell C2 and if I select Bird, C2 displays 5 and not Bird. I mad a sub routine to further test:
Sub Combo_Box()

MsgBox " Hi"

End Sub

I assigned this macro to both the combo box and list box. When I click the list box, the message box appears. When I click the combo box nothing happens.

I can't replicate your combobox issue. The listbox behaviour is as expected - both controls will return the selected list index, not the actual item. Which version and build of Mac Excel do you have?

Thanks for your reply. My Version is 16.16.25 (200810). I've opened another file I have (made from windows version) and that uses combo box. In that case, the box drops down, but is unpopulated.
